# Resource helpers in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest

As given on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, creating  a resourceful route will also expose a number of helpers to the controllers in the application. For example a resourceful route `resources :photos` will provide helpers like photos_path,new_photo_path etc.
Now, i can call a helper in the rails console using the helper object, for example `helper.link_to "this", "that"`. But calling `helper.photos_path` in the rails console does not work,however in the controller those helpers are accessible. Why is this so ?

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

route helpers are available within the `app` object, so you can get access to them this way

```
app.photos_path     # => "/photos"
```